# rails : gmaps4rails gem not showing sidebar after deployment

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have a really tiny problem that is a huge feature for the site.
Just a quick overview I developed the rails app in development mode and used the gmaps4rails app which worked fine. However I deployed the app to Heroku and now the gmaps4rails does not show the sidebar.

Below is an image of how it should look like:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJQ1X.png)
So when the user clicks on any of the sidebar entries it takes the user to the correct marker on the map.

Below is an image of how it is rendered in production/Heroku
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlNzU.png)
As you can see there is no sidebar entries.

Upon looking at the source code which is rendered there is one difference.
In the development mode this line of code is present `Gmaps.map.markers_conf.list_container = "ranchlist";` This code is the code that gets the list and displays it.

Below is the code for the view itself:

```
<div id="mapscontainer">
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"list_container" => "ranchlist"}}, 
    :map_options => {"auto_adjust" => true, "zoom" => 17,  
                                      :raw => '{ 
                                       panControl: true,
                                       zoomControl: true,
                                       mapTypeControl: false,
                                       scaleControl: false,
                                       streetViewControl: false,
                                       overviewMapControl: false,
                                       scrollwheel: false,
                                       zoom: 20,
                                       }' 
                          },
          :markers => { :data => @json  } 
)%>

<div id="ranchcontainer">
<ul id="ranchlist"><h2>Find A Mash's Wing Ranch <span style="font-size:25px;"><sup>&reg;</sup></span></h2>
<h1>Near You</h1></br>  
<%= image_tag("locations/locations_line.png", :class => "lineseperator") %> 
</ul>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem! It would be awesome for someone to help!